# Functional Derivative of action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, action, functional-derivatives

Consider the action of free Klein-Gordon theory

$S[\phi]=\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int d^4y(\partial_\mu\phi(y)\partial^\mu\phi(y)-m^2\phi^2(y))$

Integrating by parts in the first term gives me

$S[\phi]=-\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int d^4y(\phi(y)\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi(y)+m^2\phi^2(y))$

Now I take the functional derivative $\frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta\phi(x)}$ to get

$\frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta\phi(x)}=-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi(x)+2m^2\phi(x))$

Setting this equal to zero should give me the Klein-Gordon equation, but the first term is off by a factor of 2. What's wrong with what I've done?

I know there are other ways to do this. I want to know what's wrong with this way.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Note that $\partial\phi$ appears _twice_ in the kinetic term $\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2$.

Comment: $\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi}\int(\phi \partial^2\phi)\neq \partial^2\phi$, ie, the same @Qmechanic says...

Comment: @Qmechanic Sure, but I still don't see how that changes anything. $\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi=\partial_\mu(\phi\partial^\mu\phi)-\phi \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi$. Then drop the boundary term.

Comment: So the real issue is as @AccidentalFourierTransform says, which I don't see why.

Comment: @ryanp16 your doubt is actually pretty common afaik. Jut try to explicitly write the definition of funcional derivative (whatever definition you like; eg, $\phi(x)\to\phi(x)+\alpha \eta(x)$ for arbitrary $\eta(x)$ and infinitesimal $\alpha$), and see what you get. Hint: $\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi}\partial^2\phi\neq0$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Got it. Thanks. One thing though. Everything is fine if I use the $\phi\rightarrow \phi+\delta\phi$ approach. But the only way I can make it work using the approach in my question is if I can commute the functional derivative past the partial spacetime derivatives. That's an okay thing to do right? Since the partials act on the spacetime coordinates and the functional derivs act on the space of functions I think it should be okay.

Comment: @ryanp16 yeah, you almost got it. Functional and partial derivatives commute because they depend on different **spacetime variables**: the partial derivative is w.r.t. $y$ and the functional derivative is w.r.t $\phi(x)$ ($x$ vs $y$). So what you actually want to calculate is $\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(x)}\int\mathrm dy\ \phi(y)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^2 \phi(y)$: **note the spacetime dependencies**.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Great, thanks so much!

Comment: @ryanp16 :) if you are now able to answer your question, it would be nice for you to type it as an actual answer to your own question. This way, it could be useful for future reference to other users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me give a pedagogical answer. You're confused about the functional derivative

$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(y)}\int dx\, \phi(x) \partial^2 \phi(x).$$

We can compute such derivatives by perturbing a functional:

$$ F[\phi + \epsilon \chi] = F[\phi] + \epsilon \int dx \, \frac{\delta F[\phi]}{\delta \phi(x)}\chi(x) + O(\epsilon^2).$$

Now let $F[\phi] = \int dx\, \phi(x) \partial^2 \phi(x)$. Then

$$  F[\phi + \epsilon \chi] - F[\phi] = \epsilon \int dx \left[ \chi(x) \partial^2 \phi(x) + \phi(x) \partial^2 \chi(x) \right] + O(\epsilon^2). $$
But this is not of the correct form, due to the $\partial^2 \chi(x)$ term. However, you can always integrate by parts (exercise):
$$ \int dx \,  \phi(x) \partial^2 \chi(x)  = \int dx \,  \chi(x) \partial^2 \phi(x) \, + \, \text{boundary terms}.$$
By assumption, the boundary terms do not contribute. Bringing everything together, we can rewrite the formula above as

$$ F[\phi + \epsilon \chi] - F[\phi]= 2 \times \epsilon \int dx \, \chi(x) \partial^2 \phi(x)  + O(\epsilon^2).$$
At this point, we conclude that

$$ \frac{\delta F[\phi]}{\delta \phi(x)} = 2 \partial^2 \phi(x). $$

Comment: +1 It is surprising that even many "pedagogical" QFT texts do not explicitly explain this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$ A = \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(x)} \int d^{4}y \phi(y) \partial^{2} \phi(y) $$

Using the Leibniz property,

$$A = \int d^4 y \Big[\frac{\delta \phi(y)}{\delta \phi(x)} \partial^{2} \phi(y)  + \phi(y) \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(x)} \partial^{2} \phi(y)\Big] $$

Using the fact that partial and functional derivatives commute, we have:

$$ A = \int d^4 y \Big[\delta^{(4)} (y-x) \partial^{2} \phi(y)  + \phi(y)\partial^{2} \Big( \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(x)}  \phi(y) \Big)\Big]$$

Thus,

$$ A =  \partial^{2} \phi(x)  +  \int d^{4}y \phi(y)\partial^{2} \Big( \delta^{(4)}(x-y) \Big)$$

In the second term, the second derivative is on the wrong function. It should be on $\phi(y)$.

Integrate by parts and use the fact that both $\phi$ and $\delta^{(4)}$ disappear at the boundaries to show that

$$A = 2 \partial^{2} \phi(x) $$