# Confusion about dimensions of a functional, its functional derivative and its variation

Tags: field-theory, dimensional-analysis, functional-derivatives

Let's take a functional $F[\phi]$ as defined in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229288)

$$
F[\phi] = \int d^4x \, \phi\, \partial^2 \phi
$$

whose dimensions are, if the coordinates have dimensions of a length, as it's customary, are $[F]\, = [\phi^{2}]\,[L^{-2}] [L^{4}]$

It's functional derivative is
$$
\frac{\delta F[\phi]}{\delta \phi} = 2\, \partial^2 \phi
$$

This means that the dimensions of the $\displaystyle{\frac{\delta F[\phi]}{\delta \phi}}$ are $[\phi]\, [L^{-2}]$

which is equivalent to say that, assuming $[\delta\phi] = [\phi]$,
$$
[\delta F] = [\phi^2]\,[L^{-2}] = [F]\, [L^{-4}]
$$

Is this correct that $F$ and $\delta F$ have different dimensions? I find it a bit weird and I don't actually don't get why this happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, $F$ and the infinitesimal variation $\delta F$ have the same dimension. And $\phi$ and the infinitesimal variation $\delta \phi$ have the same dimension. But by definition of the [functional/variational derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) $\frac{\delta F}{\delta\phi}$, the infinitesimal variation is
$$ \delta F ~=~\color{red}{\int\!d^dx}~ \frac{\delta F}{\delta\phi}~\delta\phi. \tag{1} $$
So the functional
derivative $\frac{\delta F}{\delta\phi}$ does *not* have the dimension $\frac{[F]}{[\phi]}$, despite the notation. There is also the dimension of spacetime. Therefore
$$ \left[\frac{\delta F}{\delta\phi}\right]~=~\frac{[F]}{[\phi]\color{red}{[x]^d}}.\tag{2}$$

See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73559/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: Said another way, $\delta\phi(y)/\delta\phi(x)\equiv\delta^d(y-x)$ which has units of $[L^{-d}]$.