# Energy-momentum tensor of Nambo-Goto action?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, string-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, variational-calculus

In all lecture notes on introductory string theory people compute the energy-momentum tensor from the Polyakov action, not the Nambu-Goto action so I thought I would give that a go but I am a bit confused about the operations.

Consider the NG action
\begin{equation}
S_{NG} = \tau\int d^dx \sqrt{h}
\end{equation}
where $h$ is the induced metric. $\tau$ is the tension.

Taking the variation we get
\begin{equation}
\delta S_{NG} =  \tau\int d^dx \delta \sqrt{h}.
\end{equation}
We have the well-known relation that $\delta \sqrt{h}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{h}h_{ab} \delta h^{ab}$. Using this we get

\begin{equation}
\delta S_{NG} =  \tau \int d^dx \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{h}h_{ab} \delta h^{ab}.
\end{equation}

The energy-momentum tensor is given by $T^{ab}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{h}} \frac{\delta S_{NG}}{\delta h_{ab}}$.

Thus I think we get

\begin{equation}
T^{ab}=  \frac{-1}{\sqrt{h}}\frac{1}{\delta h_{ab}} \tau \int d^dx \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{h}h_{ab} \delta h^{ab}
\end{equation}

It seems that I have all the ingredients, but I am now uncertain how to carry out the last step.

Comment: I think you dropped a factor of $2$. Anyway, functional derivatives don't keep the integration over $x$, so it should be $T^{ab}=-\tau h^{ab}$.

Comment: Thank you @J.G. May I ask how you arrived at that?

Comment: See e.g. answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229200).

Comment: @NikoloJBar this is because of the way we define functional derivatives. In finite-dimensional spaces we have
$$df=\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i.$$
Functional derivatives are defined to generalize this relation to infinite-dimensional spaces. In other words, we want to be able to write
$$\delta S=\int d^dx \sqrt{g} \dfrac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(x)}\delta \phi(x)$$
where we see the role of the coordinates $x^i$ is played by the field values $\phi(x)$ and we replace the sum by an integral $$\sum_{i=1}^n\to \int d^dx \sqrt{g}.$$

Comment: The point is then that $\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(x)}$ does not contain the integral.